# Unable to import openpyxl module

Tags: python-3.x

The Code below works just fine :

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter, column_index_from_string
import os
os.chdir('c:\\users\\shivam\\Desktop')
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('data.xlsx')
print(wb.sheetnames)
print(get_column_letter(27))
```

but when I try to import it as:

```
from openpyxl import *
import os
os.chdir('c:\\users\\shivam\\Desktop')
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('data.xlsx')
print(wb.sheetnames)
print(get_column_letter(27))
```

it gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/python projects/excel.py", line 4, in <module>
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('data.xlsx')
NameError: name 'openpyxl' is not defined
```

Why everything from the module is not getting imported all at once?

Comment: If you use `from openpyxl import *` you need to use `load_workbook`, not `openpyxl.load_workbook`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you import a module like `import openpyxl`, then you should use `openpyxl.load_workbook`.
But while importing a module like `from openpyxl import *`, rather than importing the whole module you're importing all the classes and functions present inside the module, so there is no need of calling `openpyxl.something()`, just directly call the name of class or function like `load_workbook`